# Powerpoint 2010 C# VSTO: Adding an HTML element to a slide, keeping its original format

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to parse an Html table element to a slide from a REST service (I need it to remain as a table).
If I just manually copy the table from the result page, and paste it onto a slide - PowerPoint seems to "understand" what I was doing and displays the table as a proper PowerPoint table, including its visual style (colors, fonts, etc.).

My question is in fact two questions:

1) How does PowerPoint do that? **Can I somehow replicate this behavior with code (C#)?** There's no HTML 'Shape' to PowerPoint so how does it knows how to 'translate' the HTML table to a 'proper' PowerPoint table shape? I tried to manually copy the table to the clipboard (marking it and pressing CTRL+C) and then tried invoking:

```
PowerPoint.Slide.Shapes.Paste();
```

or:

```
PowerPoint.Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(PpPasteDataType.ppPasteHTML);
```

but both threw an exception (though the latter worked fine if I tried pasting using PpPasteDataType.ppPasteText, but of course the HTML code was pasted as plain text - which is not what I wanted).

2) Besides pasting the table or writing a (probably painful) method that breaks down the Html table and acquiring all its properties and then rebuild it as a PowerPoint table shape - how else can I achieve my goal? Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in PPT.  I can repro this (and have several times before) in VBA from w/in PPT itself.  And note that the exception occurs even when you can manually do Paste Special in PPT and see that there's HTML data on the clipboard (and you can paste it and it works as expected).

Comment: And here I was thinking that I was doing something wrong... Thanks for the info Steve.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493983/vsto-powerpoint-notes-page-different-colored-words-on-same-line/43210187#43210187